# Spring Data ElasticSearch Nested Types Inner objects mismatch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

Here's the POJO I created.

```
public class PatientDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String patientPin;

    @Field
    private String firstName;

    @Field
    private String LastName;

    @Field
    private String middleName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<Consultation> consultations;

   //getters setters...
```

Here's the Consultation

```
public class Consultation {

    private String id;

    private List<String> prescriptions;

    private List<String> diagnosis;

    private String documentDate;

    getters and setters
```

However when I check the mapping. The Consultation is not of Nested Type

```
{
  "tenant1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "patient" : {
        "properties" : {
          "consultations" : {
            "properties" : {
              "diagnosis" : {
                "type" : "string"
              },
              "documentDate" : {
                "type" : "date",
                "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
              },
              "prescriptions" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "firstName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "lastName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "middleName" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "patientPin" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```